# How to import class from a folder in the same root?

Tags: python, python-import

I have a directory like this:

```
-RootFolder/
   - lib/
       - file.py
   - source/
       - book.py
```

I'm at the `book.py`, how do I import a class from the `file.py`?

Answer (score 2):

When you are running `book.py`, only *it's* directory is gonna be added to the `sys.path` automatically. You need to make sure that the path to the `RootFolder` directory is in `sys.path`(this is where Python searches for module and packages)  then you can use absolute import :

```py
# in book.py
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, r'PATH TO \RootFolder')

from lib.file import ClassA
print(ClassA)
```

Since you added that directory, Python can find the `lib` package(namespace package, since it doesn't have `__init__.py`)

Comment: Thank u @sorousH Bakhtiary and Amadan for correcting me. BTW this thing is automatically handled if we are using some framework or anything (e.g, if we are creating a backend for some app etc).

Answer (score 1):

```
from lib.file import some_module
```

I think this should work fine if the `rootfolder` is added to path.

If not, we need to do that first as shown by @Amadan and @SorousH Bakhtiary (just wanted to add some explanation);

```
import sys
from pathlib import Path
sys.path.append(str(Path(__file__).parent.parent))
```

So here, `Path(__file__)` gives the path to the file where we are writing this code and `.parent` gives its parent directory path and so on.

Thus, `str(Path(__file__).parent.parent)` gives us path to the `RootFolder` and we are just adding that to the path.

Comment: Only if the path to the parent of `lib` is recognizable by Python.

Answer (score 1):

If you start your program from RootFolder (e.g. `python -m source.book`), the solution by Irfan wani should be perfectly fine. However, if not, then some hacking is required, to let Python know `lib` also contains relevant code:

```
import sys
from pathlib import Path
sys.path.append(str(Path(__file__).parent.parent / "lib"))
import file
```